# Send token x automatically to another address after receiving it

Tags: send-transaction

Is it possible to have something like a listener on my address so if I receive a token it will automatically transfer this token to another address?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by "listener" you mean something on-chain, somehow built into the functioning of Solana so that it takes effect automatically, then the answer is no, you cannot do that.

The closest you can come is to run a bot that constantly watches for transactions of interest and then submits a follow-up transaction to do a second transfer according to your desires.

The reason it is not possible on-chain is that there is no way for a program that does not already incorporate such functionality to be augmented to take extra actions such as follow-up transfers without changing the program itself.

You can change individual programs that you have control over, but you can't add automatic actions to existing programs that you do not own.

Comment: Correct, and if you are looking to make a bot of sorts that listens to your account read up on: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#subscription-websocket